# Изменение высоты элементов

Tags: jquery

Есть шаблон элементов на странице, которые выводятся в цикле:

```
<div class="EventMainBlock">
    <div class="TypeOfEventBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventCheckBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventStatusBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventDescriptionBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventDateBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventActionBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Из себя он представляет таблицу, но высота его под элементов не одинакова. Изменяю высоту  под элементов так :

```
$(".TypeOfEventBlock").height($(".EventDescriptionBlock").height()+2);
$(".EventCheckBlock").height($(".EventDescriptionBlock").height());
$(".EventStatusBlock").height($(".EventDescriptionBlock").height());
$(".EventDateBlock").height($(".EventDescriptionBlock").height());
$(".EventActionBlock").height($(".EventDescriptionBlock").height());
```

Но нормально срабатывает только для первого элемента, а к остальным применяет параметры первого элемента... Также не срабатывает на последнем вообще. Как нормальизовать всю работы, подскажите. Пример начала списка: [Пример](http://s42.radikal.ru/i095/1112/35/16c09da6dacf.png)

И конца списка : [Пример](http://i014.radikal.ru/1112/fc/d65ed306d0f3.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var max = 0;
$('.TypeOfEventBlock, .EventCheckBlock, .EventStatusBlock, .EventDescriptionBlock, .EventDateBlock, .EventActionBlock').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    if(h > max) max = h;
}).height(max);
```

Попробуйте так.

**Добавлено**

```
<style>
.EventMainBlock div{float:left;border:1px #000 solid;width:40px}
.TypeOfEventBlock{height:200px}
.EventCheckBlock{height:10px}
.EventStatusBlock{height:20px}
.EventDescriptionBlock{height:80px}
.EventDateBlock{height:30px}
.EventActionBlock{height:500px}
</style>
<div class="EventMainBlock">
    <div class="TypeOfEventBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventCheckBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventStatusBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventDescriptionBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventDateBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventActionBlock"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var max = 0;
$('.TypeOfEventBlock, .EventCheckBlock, .EventStatusBlock, .EventDescriptionBlock, .EventDateBlock, .EventActionBlock').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    if(h > max) max = h;
}).height(max);
</script>
```

Не понимаю, что не работает?

Comment: все отлично сработано, а можете подсказать, почему у последнего элемента нет преобразований? Прям как во втором скрине примера выше

Comment: Может, опечатка в имени класса?

Comment: Да нет, их же в цикле выводит...

Answer (score 2):

почему бы тогда не сделать фиксированую высоту в %? чем заниматься таким геморроем.
еще можно все эти TypeOfEventBlock ... EventActionBlock сделать id а не классами. или же добавить еще один класс типа

```
 <div class="EventMainBlock">
  <div class="TypeOfEventBlock _event"></div>
  <div class="EventCheckBlock _event"></div>
  <div class="EventStatusBlock _event"></div>
  <div class="EventDescriptionBlock"></div>
  <div class="EventDateBlock _event"></div>
  <div class="EventActionBlock _event"></div>
</div>
```

и тогда будет проще:

```
$("._event").height($(".EventDescriptionBlock").height());
```

но это как-то печально =/